# Problem with Insert data to Mysql with foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

```
                          <button style="margin-top: 20px;" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="addFieldset">+ Add List Items </button>
                           <div id="AddNewItems_fieldSet" ></div>
                           
                           
          <script>
 
                      //  If the user click [+ Add List Items] button this js code will run.
 
                      let fieldsetCount = 0;

                      document.getElementById("addFieldset").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                          e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission behavior
                        fieldsetCount++;
                        const fieldset = document.createElement("fieldset");
                        fieldset.innerHTML = `
                        
                        <fieldset class="form-inline">
                        
                              <h4>Item ${fieldsetCount}</h4>
                            <div style="background-color: #999999; padding: 10px; border-radius: 10px;">  
                               <div class="form-group">
                                <p>Description</p>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Description" class="form-control" aria-describedby="sizing-addon2" name="descadd${fieldsetCount}" required>
                              </div>
                                                  
              
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <p>Quantity</p>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Qty" class="form-control" name="qtyadd${fieldsetCount}" required>
                              </div>

                              <div class="form-group">  
                               <p>Unit Price</p>
                               <input type="text" value="0" placeholder="Unit Price" class="form-control" name="priceadd${fieldsetCount}">
                              </div>
                                   
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <p>Discount %</p>
                                <input type="text" value="0" placeholder="Discount %" class="form-control" name="discountadd${fieldsetCount}">
                              </div>
                                    
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <p>Total</p>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Total" class="form-control"  name="totaladd${fieldsetCount}" readonly>

                                 </div>
                                    
                            </div>  
                                  
                           </fieldset>  
                                    
                                   
                                   
                        `;
                        
                        
                        document.getElementById("AddNewItems_fieldSet").appendChild(fieldset);
                     
                      });           
            
            
            </script>                    
                                                
             
   <button style="margin-top: 20px;" type="submit" name="Submit_update" id="UpdateButton" class="btn btn-success">Update Quota</button> <!-- Add a submit button -->
                     
                   
                    <script>
 
                
                      //Form Calulation
                          function calculateTotal() {
                                        // Loop through each fieldset
                                        $('fieldset').each(function() {
                                          var qty = parseInt($(this).find('input[name^="qty"]').val());
                                          var unitPrice = parseFloat($(this).find('input[name^="price"]').val());
                                          var discount = parseFloat($(this).find('input[name^="discount"]').val());

                                          // Calculate the total based on the entered values
                                          var total = qty * unitPrice * (1 - discount / 100);

                                          // Update the total field
                                          $(this).find('input[name^="total"]').val(total.toFixed(2));
                                        });
                                      }

                                      // Event listener for quantity, unit price, and discount fields
                                      $(document).on('input', 'input[name^="qty"], input[name^="price"], input[name^="discount"]', function() {
                                        calculateTotal();
                                      });
                                              
                         
                                        // Ajax Submit jquary code
                                        $(document).ready(function() {
                                          $('#UpdateButton').click(function(e) {
                                            e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission behavior

                                            // Get form data
                                            var formData = $('#myForm_update').serialize();
                                            
                                            
                                            // Send AJAX request
                                            $.ajax({
                                              url: 'php-includes/update_quotation_ajax.php',
                                              type: 'POST',
                                              data: formData,
                                              success: function(response) {

                                                        Swal.fire({
                                                           icon: 'success',
                                                           title: 'Success',
                                                           text: 'Quotation successfully Updated!',
                                                           
                                                           
                                                         })
                                                         
                                                         
//                                                         setTimeout(function() {
//                                                            location.reload();
//                                                          }, 3000);


                                              },
                                              error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                                                        Swal.fire({
                                                           icon: 'error',
                                                           title: 'Oops...',
                                                           text: 'Something went wrong!',
                                                           
                                                         })
                                              }
                                            });
                                          });
                                        });                      

                           
                    </script>
```

```
   //-------------Inset Quotation Items------------------
    
$items = $_POST;

// Insert each item into the database
foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
    // Skip non-item fields (e.g., submit button)
    if (strpos($key, 'qtyadd') !== false) {
        $qty_add = $_POST[$key];
        $desc_add = $_POST['descadd' . substr($key, 7)];
        $price_add = $_POST['priceadd' . substr($key, 8)];
        $discount_add = $_POST['discountadd' . substr($key, 11)];
        $total_add = $_POST['totaladd' . substr($key, 8)];

        // Prepare and execute the SQL statement
        $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO qjm_quotation_Items (quo_quotation_id, quo_item_description, quo_item_qty, quo_item_unit_price, quo_item_discount, quo_item_total) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param('isdidd', $var_txt_quota_id, $desc_add, $qty_add, $price_add, $discount_add, $total_add);
        $stmt->execute();
        
        
        
    }
}        


$stmt->close();
```

users can use 'addFieldset' button to add the data to the database,
I used ajax to add the data,
Form Calulation also there with javascript.
The problem is, when the data inseting to the mysql db, only add the 'qtyadd' field data, other fields (on the database) will get empty, I think there is a problem in foreach loop.
the 'qtyadd' data pass through $qty_add = $_POST[$key]; others are not working.

how to slove this issue?

Comment: What debugging have you done? Does $_POST contain all the data you were expecting, in the format you expected? Are there any errors/warnings in php?

Comment: all this would be a lot easier if you made the names of the input fields arrays, e.g. `name="qtyadd[${fieldsetCount}]"`. that way you can do a `foreach ($_POST['qtyadd'] as $itemNo=>$qtyadd)` and apply the same key to all the other arrays

Comment: Why do you pass different values to substr each time - e.g. substr($key, 8)]; or substr($key, 11)]; when $key is the same value in each case? This doesn't seem to make sense. Have you checked this is returning what you wanted? Why not just run substr once and re-use the result?